# Visual Treelist with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm searching for a solution to make a D3.js hierarchical tree to a treelist, like in MindNode 2 (see: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6cjs1ma9n4yex3w/mindnode-treelist.png?dl=0).

As you see there are four different kinds of paths:

- a big starting point for the root
- a line (for a different parent path)
- a `⏋`-shaped curve (for parent node)
- an `├`-shaped end for node "leafs"
- an `⎿`-shaped end for the last node leaf in a hierarchy level.

I found this example that seems like to be a good start to work on: http://bl.ocks.org/thehogfather/0e48ec486abbd5be17d7

My question is now: how should I continue now? I thought about appending a svg container for each node that gets the relevant paths based on the relevant conditions. Another solution would be one gigantic svg with all its paths - but that could be the wrong way, because - as you see in the image - some nodes have much more text that has to be wrapped inside of the `li`-element.

Any solutions? Open questions? Examples :-) ?

Comment: That's how it looks like now: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dia1jicjzpv0wt/treelist-vis.png?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After muddling through the code of [this awesome example of @mbostck](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025) I found a solution and rewrote my code from treelist layout to the tree layout. But I've splitted the code in two parts: one is to build the list with `ul` and `li` HTML element. The other part is to draw the paths with just one big svg.

So the code of the first part was following:

```
  // This is my HTML container element
  var $treelistContainer = d3.select('#treelist');

  var tree = d3.layout.tree();

  var indent = 15,
      nodeTree = 0;
  var ul = $treelistContainer.append("ul").classed("treelist",true);

  var nodes = tree.nodes(data);

  var nodeEls = ul.selectAll("li.item").data(nodes);
  //list nodes
  var listEnter = nodeEls
    .enter()
      .append("li")
        .attr("class", function(d) {
          // set class to node and to leaf (for endpoints) or to root (for stem)
          var output = 'item'+(d.parent ? d.children ? '' : ' leaf' : ' root');

          // set class to even or to odd, based on its level;
          output += ((d.depth % 2) === 0 ? ' even' : ' odd');

          return output;
        })
        .attr("id", function(d,i){return "id"+i})
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("background-color", function(d) {
          return colorgrey(d.depth);
        })
        .append("span").attr("class", "value")
          .style("padding-left", function (d) {
            return 20 + d.depth * indent + "px";
          })
          .html(function (d) { return d.name; });
```

That builds the whole HTML list for the project. Now here comes the magic of the next part: you have to recalculate the `x`, `y`. I also used a value called `nodeTree` to give every hierarchy an own ID to choose a different color for it. So here's the code:

```
var nodeTree = 0;
var rootTop = d3.selectAll('li.item')
    .filter(function(d,i) {
      return i == 0;
    })
    .node()
      .getBoundingClientRect()
        .top;
nodes.forEach(function(n, i) {
  // Get position of li element
  var top = d3.selectAll('li.item')
    .filter(function(d2,i2) {
      return i2 == i;
    })
    .node()
      .getBoundingClientRect()
        .top;
  n.x = top - rootTop;//i * 38;
  n.y = n.depth * indent;
  if (n.depth == 1) nodeTree++;
  n.value = nodeTree;
});
```

Now I simply read out x, y and the value to calculate it's diagonal position. Before I have to build the container and calculate some other things

```
  var width = $treelistContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().width,
      height = $treelistContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().height,
      i = 0,
      id = 0,
      margin = {top: 20, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15};

  var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

  var svg = $treelistContainer
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width - margin.left - margin.right+"px")
      .attr("height", height+"px")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(tree.links(nodes))
      .enter()
        .insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("stroke", function(d) {

          // Setting the color based on the hierarchy
          console.log(d.target.value);
          return color(d.target.value);
        })
        .attr("d", function(d,i) {
          var source = {x: d.source.x, y: d.source.y};
          var target = {x: d.target.x, y: d.target.y};
          return diagonal({source: source, target: target});
        });
```

And here's how it looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysbszycoiost72t/result.png?dl=0

I will try to optimize it by changing the interpolation type, adding some little colorful node circles and so on.

Hope this will help someone.